# Why is this PHP script not sending the e-mail?

Tags: php, email

**Note:** E-Mail address removed for privacy purposes.

Whenever the form executes this script, it returns the success JSON array at the end, however, the e-mail is never received at the e-mail address specified.

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['fullname']) || empty($_POST['phonenumber']) || empty($_POST['emailaddress']))
    {
    $response = array('status' => 0, 'txt' => 'Please verify all required fields are complete.');
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
    }

if(!(preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $_POST['emailaddress'])))
    {
    $response = array('status' => 0, 'txt' => 'Please Provide a Valid E-Mail Address.');
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
    }

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
$phonenumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumber']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailaddress']);
$comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);

$emailbody = 'Name: ' . $name . ' 
Phone Number: ' . $phonenumber . ' 
E-Mail Address: ' . $email . ' 

Comments: ' . $comments . ' ';

mail("example@example.com","New Consultation Request",$emailbody,"From: noreply@example.com"); 

$response = array('status' => 1, 'txt' => 'consultation-request-successful');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Just to be safe, have you checked the receiving inbox's spam folder?

Comment: You are connected to DB before executing this, right? Otherwise if you're not, your variables will be overwritten by nothing. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - One must look at all possible contributing scenarios ;-) (...and they called Einstein a crazy 'ol fool).

Comment: Did you bother starting with the basics, like checking the return value of `mail()`? If it's boolean FALSE, then mail is broken and you need to fix it. if it's true, then you go look at the mail server's logs and see what happened after php handed over the email.

Answer (score 0):

You've never bothered connecting to the database, so `mysql_real_escape_string()` is going to be turning a boolean FALSE for failure - it **REQUIRES** an active connection to the DB to do its work.

That means your `$name, $phonenumber, $email, $comments` are all going to be boolean FALSE, and translated into an empty string when you build your mail text.

As well, using mysql escaping for a simple email is beyond utterly pointless. Email is not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.